# Отождествление идентификатор сеанса с идентификатором соединения

Tags: архитектура, сетевое-программирование

Правильно ли отождествлять идентификатор сеанса с идентификатором соединения (socket native handle)?

Описание: 
Cущность connection - это обертка для сетевого сокета, при создании нового соединения экземпляр connection передается session_manager, который и создает новый сеанс. Сейчас в качестве идентификатора сеанса выступает идентификатор соединения. Если я правильно понимаю, не может быть такой ситуации, когда у нас есть два сеанса с одинаковыми идентификаторам, т.к. если соединение было закрыто - то сам сеанс так же был завершен.

Возможно, я не предусмотрел некоторые кейсы, и данный подход ошибочен - если так, прошу указать на недостатки.

Comment: А это смотря что считать сеансом. Например в  обычном http "сеанс" обычно определяют внешними идентификаторами, например через куки, просто потому, что каждый запрос в пределах сеанса делается через отдельное соединение

Comment: @Mike, в данном случае под сеансом понимается TCP-сессия. Т.е., клиент и сервер общаются в "пределах" одного соединения.